# the same onclick event multiple times in a forum - needing automated unique IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid, forum

I'm coding a forum and in the user description besides every post there is a div with an onclick event. The problem now is... I coded the event with IDs and it works just fine! BUT... if I got two or more posts on a thread, the onclick description only works for the first post. The second and third etc. post, nothing happens (not even the description in the first post changes when I click the onclick event in the second post).

I think its because IDs need to be unique...

Is there a method that lets every ID be unique like... in the second post, its automatically ID2, in the third its ID3 etc.? Does anything like that exist?

I'm a newb and would reeaaally appreciate your help.

Does anyone have an idea? I'm stuck.

Comment: I'm reading a lot about automated unique IDs now but I just don't get how to use it for my example. Is it even possible? Or do I need a different approach for my problem?

Comment: as you say its a `post`, doesn't the post have an id on the server? Is it not possible to send the id along with the post ?

Comment: oh yeah, every post has a unique id, a "pid", and I love that approach! Now I gave every ID the pid with a variable, like this: postbitbutt1{$post['pid']} ... but now the links of the second and third post just changes the content of the first post. It seems to fill it only with the ID of the first post. :/

Comment: oh, i had to do it with the content-divs as well... now it works, wow!!! Thank you so much haha (how can I give you a thanks or a thumbs up or i dont know? haha)

Comment: without code, we cant predict what is the logic implemented.